# Update data in Ui from Preload.js

Tags: electron, electron-builder

[image: this is my directory structure]

In preload.js. I have a server which listen for upcoming api call on /run. Now I want to update the ui in home.html from what ever the data I get in test_runner_steps.
Whenever some data changes happens i want to update the ui in home.html

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('express', { 
    startServer: () => { 
        expressListen = expressApp.listen(3009, () => {
            console.log('Server started on port 3009');
        })
        expressApp.post('/run', (req, res) => { 
            const { test_runner_steps } = req.body
           
            res.send('Hello World!');
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to run a web server in the renderer process of your application, let alone its preload script? I suggest reading up on [Electron's process model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner i have moved all code from preload to index(main) file. Now i am running things via ipcMain.handle and in preload i am exposing functions using contextbride and calling  index file function via ipcRenderer invoke and its working that way. Having things in preload was a bad idea. Is there any good approach that you can suggest.